# How to animate multiple SVG paths in a pie/donut chart in sequence with SMIL/CSS

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, smil

I have an svg group that contains a series of paths which represent different areas of a pie chart these paths are convered by a circle tag and the graph appears as a donut chart.

```html
<svg width="71" height="70" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g class="graph-arc" transform="translate(1,1)">
        <path stroke="#3f88c5" fill="#3f88c5" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55386505302874, 0.9532377462801749 z" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(225, 34.5, 34.5)"></path>
        <path stroke="#3f88c5" fill="#3f88c5" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55386505302874, 0.9532377462801749 z" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(238.5, 34.5, 34.5)"></path>
        <path stroke="#3A8DC3" fill="#3A8DC3" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55386505302874, 0.9532377462801749 z" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(252, 34.5, 34.5)"></path>
        <path stroke="#3593BF" fill="#3593BF" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55386505302874, 0.9532377462801749 z" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(265.5, 34.5, 34.5)"></path>
        <path stroke="#3398BE" fill="#3398BE" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55386505302874, 0.9532377462801749 z" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(279, 34.5, 34.5)"></path>
        <path stroke="#3398BE" fill="#3398BE" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55386505302874, 0.9532377462801749 z" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(292.5, 34.5, 34.5)"></path>
        <path stroke="#359DBB" fill="#359DBB" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55386505302874, 0.9532377462801749 z" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(306, 34.5, 34.5)"></path>
        <path stroke="#36A3B9" fill="#36A3B9" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55386505302874, 0.9532377462801749 z" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(319.5, 34.5, 34.5)"></path>
        <path stroke="#36A3B9" fill="#36A3B9" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55386505302874, 0.9532377462801749 z" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(333, 34.5, 34.5)"></path>
        <path stroke="#38A8B6" fill="#38A8B6" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55386505302874, 0.9532377462801749 z" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(346.5, 34.5, 34.5)"></path>
        <path stroke="#39ADB4" fill="#39ADB4" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55386505302874, 0.9532377462801749 z" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(360, 34.5, 34.5)"></path>
        <path stroke="#39ADB4" fill="#39ADB4" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55386505302874, 0.9532377462801749 z" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(373.5, 34.5, 34.5)"></path>
        <path stroke="#3BB3B2" fill="#3BB3B2" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55386505302874, 0.9532377462801749 z" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(387, 34.5, 34.5)"></path>
        <path stroke="#3DB8AE" fill="#3DB8AE" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55386505302874, 0.9532377462801749 z" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(400.5, 34.5, 34.5)"></path>
        <path stroke="#3DB8AE" fill="#3DB8AE" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55386505302874, 0.9532377462801749 z" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(414, 34.5, 34.5)"></path>
        <path stroke="#3EBDAD" fill="#3EBDAD" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55386505302874, 0.9532377462801749 z" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(427.5, 34.5, 34.5)"></path>
        <path stroke="#40C3AA" fill="#40C3AA" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55386505302874, 0.9532377462801749 z" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(441, 34.5, 34.5)"></path>
        <path stroke="#40C3AA" fill="#40C3AA" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55386505302874, 0.9532377462801749 z" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(454.5, 34.5, 34.5)"></path>
        <path stroke="#00c8a8" fill="#00c8a8" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55386505302874, 0.9532377462801749 z" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(468, 34.5, 34.5)"></path>
        <path stroke="#00c8a8" fill="#00c8a8" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55386505302874, 0.9532377462801749 z" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(481.5, 34.5, 34.5)"></path>
        <path stroke="#e5e5e5" fill="#e5e5e5" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 34.5, 0 z" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(495, 34.5, 34.5)"></path>
    </g>
    <circle r="25.875" cx="35.5" cy="35.5" fill="#fff"></circle> . 
</svg>
```

I would like the overall effect to be like this: https://codepen.io/seanstopnik/pen/GqHng

There are many examples using stroke-dasharray for lines but I haven't been able to find anything for animating multiple paths! What is the best way to do this?

Comment: using multiple path isn't the good way I guess. You should probably consider a gradient coloration instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Temani Afif commented using multiple path isn't the good way. This is how I would do it:

To calculate the path length (155.53) I've used JS & the method `getTotalLength`. I've calculated the path as an arc with a radius of 33 units starting at `3*Math.PI/4` and ending at `Math.PI/4`.

*The animation happens on mouse over*.

```css
svg{border:1px solid;width:90vh}

#thePath{
  stroke-dasharray : 155.53px;
  stroke-dashoffset : 155.53px;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset .5s;
}

svg:hover #thePath{
  stroke-dashoffset : 0px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox ="0 0 71 70" id="svg">
<defs>
  <linearGradient id="lg">
   <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#3f88c5"></stop>
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#00c8a8"></stop>
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
  
  <path id="thePath" d="M12.165476220843935,58.33452377915607A33,33,0 1 1 58.834523779156065,58.334523779156065" fill="none" stroke="url(#lg)" stroke-width="4" />
</svg>
```

And this is the code where I'm using JS to calculate all this:

```js
let R = 33;// the radius of the arc for the path
// the starting point of the path
let x = 35.5 + R * Math.cos(3 * Math.PI / 4);
let y = 35 + R * Math.sin(3 * Math.PI / 4);
// the end point of the path
let _x = 35.5 + R * Math.sin(Math.PI / 4);
let _y = 35 + R * Math.sin(Math.PI / 4);
// the value of the d attribute of the path
let d = `M${x},${y}A${R},${R},0 1 1 ${_x},${_y}`;
thePath.setAttributeNS(null, "d", d);

let pathLength = thePath.getTotalLength();

thePath.setAttribute(
  "style",
  `stroke-dasharray : ${pathLength}px; stroke-dashoffset : ${pathLength}px;`
);
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid;width:90vh;}

#thePath{ 
  transition: stroke-dashoffset .5s;
}

svg:hover #thePath{
  stroke-dashoffset : 0px!important;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox ="0 0 71 70" id="svg">
<defs>
  <linearGradient id="lg">
   <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#3f88c5"></stop>
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#00c8a8"></stop>
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
  
  <path id="thePath" fill="none" stroke="url(#lg)" stroke-width="4" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a stroke to animate, as per the normal method.  So what you can to is turn the animated stroked line into a mask.  Then apply that mask to your more complicated shape.

```css
#progress circle {
  animation: do-progress 4s infinite;
}

@keyframes do-progress {
    0% { stroke-dashoffset: 0px; }
   50% { stroke-dashoffset: -146px; }
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 0px; }
}
```

```html
<svg width="71" height="70" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <mask id="progress" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <rect x="-1" y="-1" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff"/>
            <circle r="30.5" cx="34.5" cy="34.5" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="146 192" transform="rotate(-227, 34.5, 34.5)"/>
        </mask>
    </defs>
    <g class="graph-arc" transform="translate(1,1)" mask="url(#progress)">
        <path stroke="#3f88c5" fill="#3f88c5" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55, 0.95 z" transform="rotate(225, 34.5, 34.5)"/>
        <path stroke="#3f88c5" fill="#3f88c5" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55, 0.95 z" transform="rotate(238.5, 34.5, 34.5)"/>
        <path stroke="#3A8DC3" fill="#3A8DC3" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55, 0.95 z" transform="rotate(252, 34.5, 34.5)"/>
        <path stroke="#3593BF" fill="#3593BF" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55 0.95 z" transform="rotate(265.5, 34.5, 34.5)"/>
        <path stroke="#3398BE" fill="#3398BE" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55, 0.95 z" transform="rotate(279, 34.5, 34.5)"/>
        <path stroke="#3398BE" fill="#3398BE" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55, 0.95 z" transform="rotate(292.5, 34.5, 34.5)"/>
        <path stroke="#359DBB" fill="#359DBB" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55, 0.95 z" transform="rotate(306, 34.5, 34.5)"/>
        <path stroke="#36A3B9" fill="#36A3B9" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55, 0.95 z" transform="rotate(319.5, 34.5, 34.5)"/>
        <path stroke="#36A3B9" fill="#36A3B9" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55, 0.95 z" transform="rotate(333, 34.5, 34.5)"/>
        <path stroke="#38A8B6" fill="#38A8B6" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55, 0.95 z" transform="rotate(346.5, 34.5, 34.5)"/>
        <path stroke="#39ADB4" fill="#39ADB4" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55, 0.95 z" transform="rotate(360, 34.5, 34.5)"/>
        <path stroke="#39ADB4" fill="#39ADB4" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55, 0.95 z" transform="rotate(373.5, 34.5, 34.5)"/>
        <path stroke="#3BB3B2" fill="#3BB3B2" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55, 0.95 z" transform="rotate(387, 34.5, 34.5)"/>
        <path stroke="#3DB8AE" fill="#3DB8AE" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55, 0.95 z" transform="rotate(400.5, 34.5, 34.5)"/>
        <path stroke="#3DB8AE" fill="#3DB8AE" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55, 0.95 z" transform="rotate(414, 34.5, 34.5)"/>
        <path stroke="#3EBDAD" fill="#3EBDAD" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55, 0.95 z" transform="rotate(427.5, 34.5, 34.5)"/>
        <path stroke="#40C3AA" fill="#40C3AA" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55, 0.95 z" transform="rotate(441, 34.5, 34.5)"/>
        <path stroke="#40C3AA" fill="#40C3AA" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55, 0.95 z" transform="rotate(454.5, 34.5, 34.5)"/>
        <path stroke="#00c8a8" fill="#00c8a8" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55, 0.95 z" transform="rotate(468, 34.5, 34.5)"/>
        <path stroke="#00c8a8" fill="#00c8a8" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 42.55, 0.95 z" transform="rotate(481.5, 34.5, 34.5)"/>
        <path stroke="#e5e5e5" fill="#e5e5e5" d="M 34.5,34.5 L34.5,0 A34.5,34.5 0 0,1 34.5, 0 z" transform="rotate(495, 34.5, 34.5)"/>
    </g>
    <circle r="25.875" cx="35.5" cy="35.5" fill="#fff"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, Paul. Masking it is a great idea! I'm using react and the animation is cut when the component updates. How could it be done by masking off individual sections SMIL?
I'd like to have something like:
```
    <g>
        <arc />
        <maskingArc>
             <animate />
        </maskingArc>
    </g>
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Do you mean that you would like to know how to do it with SVG animation elements (ie `<animate>` )?

Comment: I was referring to masking each individual path and using animate. But I've figured most of that out.  What I am still curious about is the stroke-dasharray: 146 192 numbers. How did you come up with them? Based on the distance/circumference of the arc?  And what is the relationship between the stroke-dasharray on the circle and the stroke-dashoffset in the animation?

Comment: 192 is the circumference of a circle with radius of 30.5. It didn't actuallyy need to be that big.  146 would have been okay.  The 146 was found by experimentation. I rotated the circle so that the stroke start point matched the start (left end) of your arc. Then adjusted the value until it covered the whole of the arc.